# Using more than one OR Operator in an If Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to do an IF statement with 4 conditional. It doesn't seem to be working though and to be honest I'm not sure if you should be able to make something like this work?

I'd like the text in the if block to show if any one of these conditions are met but at the moment it's only picking in the first two.

```
if(($message[to] == "") || ($person == $message[to]) || ($name == $person) || ($user[group] == "admin")){
     echo "This is a test";
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: probably it doesn't affect your condition but in php it is always a good practise tu unse quotes for array index: $message['to']

Comment: Don't forget the quotes when accessing arrays. It's not `$message[to]` but `$message['to']`.

Comment: If this code is not behaving as you expect, then the values of `$name` and `$person` are probably not what you think they are.

Comment: `/waves hand` "these are not the variables you are looking for..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
if((empty($message['to'])) || ($person == $message['to']) || ($name == $person) || ($user['group'] == "admin")){
     echo "This is a test";
 }
```

Also use a print_r($message), print_r($user), etc to see if they really have the values you think.

Comment: Bad suggestion.  `empty($message['to'])` is **not** the same as `$message['to']==''`.  [(manual entry)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: yes... it sees if is also defined. also returns true if the first condition ($message['to']=='') is valid. so... good suggestion. anyway... give me a reason why u think is wrong.

Comment: If `$message['to']=='0'` then `empty` will return true.  See the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).